# How to Display Database table row count in vue component with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a database table with and 145 records and i need to display the row count in vue js component using laravel

How can i display the reocrd count as 145 in vuejs component

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `.length` to your data, follow this example : https://jsfiddle.net/gfL51knz/1/